# which android default color resources have a dark mode variant?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

Is there a list of default color resources that automatically switch to a dark mode variant?

for example here I would like to have the same color for the arrow in the dark mode as the text next to it. Which tint do I have to apply?

[image: light mode example]

[image: dark mode example]

I know there is values.xml where I already found some that helped me out like `@color/material_on_surface_emphasis_high_type`

[image]

but thats also not the same color as the text. arrow is 999999, text is B3B3B3

Is there a list of colors that could be used or do I have to try every seemingly possible resource from values.xml?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do that in code. It simple example but it can work if you want to do both in one color.

```
val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)?.currentTextColor
val arrow = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.arrow)?.setTextColor( text!!)
```